# Static block only in mobile view

Tags: magento-1.9

Is there a way to configure from admin panel a static block to be shown only in mobile view? I want to add a static block "install our mobile application". This block should be seen only by users who access my website from a mobile device.

Thank you!

Comment: no i don't think there is any configure related mobile view in static view

Comment: Magento confuration not provide this, but you can archive this using css strick same as other things handel in responsive theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your static block you can do this trick

```
<div class="cms-block-mobile">

    your content 
</div>
<style>
.cms-block-mobile{
    display:none;
}
@media only screen  and (max-width : 640px) {
    .cms-block-mobile{
        display:block;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank youI I'll try this

Comment: You are always Welcome :)